# How do create a "manager class" with events for android?

Tags: java, android, class, events

Thank you, for reading this ;)

I have a class "scanner" with events that trigger when a barcode gets scanned and three activities. I want to let the user switch from activity to activity, but when an event is triggered in "scanner" i want the "scanner" class to start/resume a new activity (one of the three).

So, basically i want to create a "manager class" which events will always trigger, even if another activity is on the foreground.

How do i do this? I am coming from Xamarin Android so my Java knowledge isn't that great...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Java equivalent for event is an Observer design Pattern. If you look at the button Click handler you'll see listener interface. Listener is an Observer of the event.
2. If you want to handle navigation from any activity you need to have single navigation manager shared by activities. You can create singleton in Application inherited class.  See [how this is achieved](https://www.intertech.com/Blog/androids-application-class/). And subscribe to scanner events using observer pattern. Then since you need to get access to navigation manager create base activity class and implement there Navigation Manager member and navigation methods. Inherit from this base activity your's 3 activities.